# Probability equality related to simultaneous confidence intervals

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_q$ be a set of parameters and let $(a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_q,b_q)$ be pairs of random variables where $a_i<b_i$ with probability 1 for all $i$. Show that $$\text{Pr}\left\{ a_i\leq \tau_i\leq b_i \text{ for all } i=1,\ldots,q\right\} = \text{Pr}\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^q u_ia_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^q u_i\tau_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^q u_ib_i \text{ for all } u_i \geq 0\right\}$$

I am having trouble rigourously showing this. Here is my attempt:

Let $u_1,\ldots,u_q$ be non-negative constants. Then $$\text{Pr}\left\{ a_i\leq \tau_i\leq b_i \text{ for all } i=1,\ldots,q\right\} = \text{Pr}\left\{ u_ia_i\leq u_i\tau_i\leq u_ib_i \text{ for all } i=1,\ldots,q\right\}$$ since this holds for all $i=1,\ldots,q$ then the set of events that satisfies $\left\{  u_ia_i\leq u_i\tau_i\leq u_ib_i \text{ for all }\right\}$ is the same as the set $\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^q u_ia_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^q u_i\tau_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^q u_ib_i\right\}$. Hence the equality holds.

My attempt doesn't sit well with me, is there a better way to show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_i\leq \tau_i\leq b_i \text{ for all } i=1,\ldots,q$, then $u_i a_i\leq u_i \tau_i\leq u_i b_i \text{ for all } u_i \geq 0$ (as the real numbers are an ordered field) and so $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^q u_ia_i  \leq \sum_{i=1}^q u_i\tau_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^q u_ib_i \text{ for all } u_i \geq 0$.

In the other direction, if $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^q u_ia_i  \leq \sum_{i=1}^q u_i\tau_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^q u_ib_i \text{ for all } u_i \geq 0$, then it is  true in particular when $u_j=1$ and $u_i=0$ for $i \not= j$, i.e. $a_j\leq \tau_j\leq b_j \text{ for each } j=1,\ldots,q$.